# Webservice or Webapp?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, web-applications

i have already made a RESTFul web service using Spring to be consumed by various mobile clients. Now if in future I need to make a web-portal to implement the same functionalities, which will be a more appropriate option and why ? please provide proper citations if possible

Option1: I make a new webapp which will consume the previously made RESTFul webservices
Option2: I make a new webapp using the previously made codebase for RESTFul (maybe some modification required at controller layer) and integrating those JAVA code with the new webapp.

Which is more better or recommended approach and why? please provide citations too if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my views:

Option 1: This is good option, it will have service based dependency which will avoid changing the webapp code if any implementation changes in services. However with this it will add extra translation in new webapp.

Option 2: This will have tight coupling between service and client(new webapp). Client and server cannot evolve independently without making changes in new app. There would be constant code changes in both the project.

I would suggest you to go with Option 1. Also I have suggestion on RESTful services design. It can be designed with interfaces for all controllers or extract interfaces from existing controllers and those can be exposed as EJB for internal clients like new webapp. This way same services can be exposed using RESTful and EJB with same implementation.

Comment: Can you provide any insight as how to design with interfaces for all controllers or extract interfaces from existing controller. And how to expose it? I am a newbie in J2EE so i dont have much knowledge. Would be helpful if you could provide any link to an example..

Comment: @NayanjyotiDeka Yes, you can refer my sample project at **https://github.com/sachinb4u/emp-service**. It has RESTful web service designed with interface which is also exposed as Stateless EJB.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 will avoid code repetition, but will force you to make remote invocations with the corresponding performance penalization.

Option 2 will duplicate code on two projects, which is not a good idea.

I suggest you an Option 3, consisting on factorizing your first project, and putting the common code on a jar to be referenced from both the REST API project and the Web app project.

Comment: No, the op said option 2 would simply add to the existing code base so there would be no duplication. It would in essence be simply adding more end points which happen to produce HTML instead of JSON or XML.

Comment: Actually, the OP was a bit vague so your interpretation could be valid. The "new webapp" suggests a new code base as you interpreted but I suspect he meant add to existing codebase.

Comment: The addition of code will adding more endpoints as mentioned by nickdos.

Can you provide more insight into the option 3 you suggested? Maybe a link which will give me more insight into the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Only you can really answer this question as you have far more information about the project than we do (or that you have provided). Both options are valid and the choice of which depends on the specifics of the project. More importantly the decision should be the one that benefits the user the most.

Having said that, I have been in this situation on a number of times and I've gone with both options. Both work but I'd choose option 1 more often than option 2 based on my experiences. I'd use Grails or a modern javascript framework (like Angular JS) to produce a client only app that consumes your web services. This has the benefit of being small and modular, allowing you to "eat your own dog food", and provides example code for others to use to write apps to consume your web services.